# Using template parameters as template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Why is the following code invalid?

```
template <typename S, typename T>
struct B{
    void f(T t, S s) {t.f<S>(s); }
};
```

gcc 4.3.4 complains that it "expected primary-expression before '>' token", i.e. that "S" wasn't a valid primary-expression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify that `f` is a template:

```
void f(T t, S s) {
    t.template f<S>(s);
}
```

C++ doesn’t know this (at this point) since `f`’s type depends on the type of the template parameter `T`. Furthermore, the following syntax would be ambiguous: does `<` mean the start of a template list or a less-than operator? To help C++ figure that out you need to specify that `f` is a template, otherwise C++ cannot parse the following part because the *parse itself* depends on the type of `T`.

Comment: VS can parse it though (lazy parsing?), it's just a C++ standard restriction

Comment: @coyotte508 VS uses a two-pass parser to handle this. This is of course possible, but quite inefficient. The restriction of a single pass in the standard makes a lot of sense, especially considering that computers weren’t always as fast as today, and C++ compilers are *still* very slow.

Comment: That's great to know. It's not the only instance in which GCC behaves this way (something with it requiring to use using BaseClass::function if BaseClass is a template parameter), so personnally I don't mind trading some compilation time for this, but I understand now why the restriction.

Answer (score 1):

You also can rely on type inference to infer the template type instead of explicitly stating it.  Then you would have "t.f(s);", which is actually a slightly more generic way to state it: you probably don't care that f is a templated function, you just want it to have some definition for f that accepts an S.

Comment: I think type inference would have failed in the actual code, because of polymorphism.  f looked like template<S> void f(S&), and I wanted to instantiate f<Parent>(Child&), which isn't clear from the example code.